# uploading file to ftp server in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I am trying to upload a file on ftp server using node.js as below-

I am using library- https://github.com/sergi/jsftp

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Ftp = new JSFtp({
    host: "ftp.some.net",
    port: 21, // defaults to 21
    user: "username", // defaults to "anonymous"
    pass: "pass",
    debugMode: true // defaults to "@anonymous"
});
```

**Uploading file-**

```
exports.UploadToFtP = function (req, res) {
     Ftp.put('public/Test.html', '/Test/index.html', function (err) {
            if (!err)
                res.send(200);
            else
                res.send(err);
        });
};
```

I tried uploading file with this method above and it responds me back with `200 OK` . But I get no file on server.
Is this has to do something with connection time out of server ? Why this is not writing file on server?

Comment: Did you solve the problem now?

Answer (score 2):

If the debug mode is on, the jsftp instance will emit jsftp_debug events.

In order to react to print all debug events, we would listen to the debug messages like this:

```
Ftp.on('jsftp_debug', function(eventType, data) {
    console.log('DEBUG: ', eventType);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

Comment: how do I turn debug mode on?

Answer (score 0):

> The raw FTP accepts no parameters and returns the farewell
> message from the server. Embed raw FTP function in the FTP GET method

> We can use raw FTP commands directly as well. In this case, we use FTP
> 'QUIT' method, which accepts no parameters and returns the farewell
> message from the server

```
ftp.raw.quit(function(err, res) {
    if (err)
        return console.error(err);

    console.log("FTP session finalized! See you soon!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The file needs to be converted to bytes first.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('example.txt', function (err, data ) {
    Ftp.put(data, 'example.txt', function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('OK');
        } else {
            console.log('ERR');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).